# CLion How to move resource files into build directory

Tags: cmake, clion

```
project(Brendan-C-SFML)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "$ENV{SFML_ROOT}/cmake/Modules")

find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS main system window graphics audio)

add_executable(Brendan-C-SFML brendan-c.cpp)

target_include_directories(Brendan-C-SFML PRIVATE ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Brendan-C-SFML ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

I have a `share` folder which should be in the same directory as `Brendan-C-SFML.exe` but CLion builds out-of-source so `share` is not accessible. Is there a way to set up CLion to copy `share` to the build directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following line to the end of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
file(COPY share DESTINATION ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
```

Try reloading the `cmake` config in case the copy doesn't work. Use `File -> Reload CMake Project` to reload the cmake config.

Comment: For me it was `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` instead of `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}` (on MacOS)

Comment: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} on Debian also.

Comment: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} on Windows as well.