# SFML - failed to load image - unable to open file - LINUX

Tags: c++, linux, image, sfml, clion

### Description of problem

I was developing my project on **ubuntu** (clion ide) but I changed distribution to **xubuntu** and cloned the same repository to it. Unfortunately, each image which I include in project generate this runtime error:

```
Failed to load image "image.png". Reason: Unable to open file
```

SFML is installed correctly because I checked it with standard program from [SFML Site](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php). I didn't have that problem on ubuntu.

### My try

I think that there is a problem with permissions of files. So I create sample project (as below), added **player.png** and I get the same error. So I use that command in terminal:

```
chmod a+w player.png
```

It doesn't solve a problem. I am new in linux so maybe there is something more to do, but I don't know. I also tried different ways from this site and SFML forum but it doesn't helps me. 
 I also tried to load other images, doesn't work too.

### Code

There is sample code which I have created to find problem. It is only modified sample from [SFML Site](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php).

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "SFML works!");
    sf::Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("player.png");
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(t);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Solution and another problem:

What is interesting,

```
    t.loadFromFile("../player.png");
```

solved the problem. 
By default, sfml expected the image to be in `cmake-build-debug` folder... 

**How to add default directory to my project, not to cmake folder?**

Comment: I presume you are also using CLion on xubuntu? Maybe add the `clion` tag. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32535461/2836621

Comment: I will try as soon as I come back to home @MarkSetchell, thanks for link

Comment: You have to change the working directory in CLion. You might want to have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834878/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-for-my-program

Comment: @Unterfliege - you have right - changing directory works! Can you write the same thing in answer? I will mark it as the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an option to change your current working directory. This can be done either using CLion or CMake.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834878/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-for-my-program) where you can find answers which describe both ways.